# A/B testing a product landing page

Tags: rules-engine, content-testing

I am trying to figure out if the following use cases are supported natively in Sitecore 9 or if there would be custom development (and if so, the best approach to leverage):

**Simplified Test Scenario** - A/B test of the Products landing page to a subset of visitors

> **Eligibility requirements:**
>
> 1. User is on the page
> 2. User is logged in and the session holds the user type set to 'active member'
> 3. Running Sitecore 9.01 - all marketing features on etc.
>
> **Test:**
>
> 1. For members only, run an A/B test to swap components in the hero area to explore which option resonates better to members

So I'm wondering - would a custom rule for the rules engine to test for membership type be the only thing to add? I'm not sure whether the rules engine can interact with the A/B tests being run.

If not, what's the best path to achieve this user story?

Thanks!

-Chris

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  What you're looking for is a component test, not an A/B test.  The A/B test tests a full page against another page or version of the same page.  The component test applies a test against all the component variations on a page.  Any time you personalize a component (e.g., active member gets component variant A) you have the ability to run component testing on that personalization.  In most Sitecore configurations (as long as you're not logged in as an administrator) you should see a blue message bar that asks you if you want to start a test once you've personalized a component.

[image]